# Как сделать, чтоб select работал в регистрации

Tags: php, html

```
<label for="demo-category">Position</label>
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select>
        <option type="text" name="position" id="position" value="" class="optionGroup" hidden>Select a position</option>
        <optgroup label="Deck">         
            <option value="d1">Master</option>
            <option value="d2">Chief Officer</option>
            <option value="d3">Single Officer</option>
            <option value="d4">2nd Officer</option>
            <option value="d5">3rd Officer</option>
            <option value="d6">Senior DPO</option>
            <option value="d7">Junior DPO</option>
            <option value="d8">DPO</option>
            <option value="d9">Trainee Officer</option>
            <option value="d10">Bosun (Boatswain)</option>
            <option value="d11">AB (Able Seaman)</option>
            <option value="d12">AB/Welder</option>
            <option value="d13">OS (Ordinary Seaman)</option>
            <option value="d14">Deck Cadet</option>
            <option value="d15">Cadet/Trainee</option>
            <option value="d16">Chief Cook</option>
            <option value="d17">Cook</option>
            <option value="d18">2nd Cook</option>
            <option value="d19">Messboy</option>
            <option value="d20">AB/Cook</option>
            <option value="d21">Crane Operator</option>
            <option value="d22">Dredge Master</option>
            <option value="d23">Diver</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Engine">
            <option value="e1">Chief Engineer</option>
            <option value="e2">Single</option>
            <option value="e3">2nd Engineer</option>
            <option value="e4">3rd Engineer</option>
            <option value="e5">4th Engineer</option>
            <option value="e6">Watch Engineer</option>
            <option value="e7">Ref. Engineer</option>
            <option value="e8">Gas Engineer</option>
            <option value="e9">Trainee Engineer</option>
            <option value="e10">Electrial Engineer</option>
            <option value="e11">ETO</option>
            <option value="e12">Electrician</option>
            <option value="e13">Assistant Electrical Engineer</option>
            <option value="e14">Motorman/Oiler</option>
            <option value="e15">Wiper</option>
            <option value="e16">Motorman/Electrician</option>
            <option value="e17">AB/MM</option>
            <option value="e18">Engine Cadet</option>
            <option value="e19">Fitter/Welder</option>
            <option value="e20">Turner</option>
            <option value="e21">Pumpman</option>
            <option value="e22">Superintendent</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>

<?php
    if($user_position=='')
    {
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the position')</script>";
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Выдает ошибку, что надо поменять? input нету, так как это опции

Вставил свойства input в опции, но все равно ошибка

```
<option type="text" name="position" id="position" value="" class="optionGroup" hidden>Select a position</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.

Вам нужно указать параметр name для тэга select. И по этому имени вы будете получать выделенное значение: select name="selectionvalue"